# using MVC 6 with IIS Express and nested application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-express

I have a web application that I build in MVC 6 that has a webforms application as a nested web app.  I am able to run this successfully in IIS by manually setting up a web application that points to my published MVC 6 wwwroot folder.  I then create a nested web application that points to my webforms project folder.  I am able to access pages in my underlying webforms project without any trouble.

I am trying to replicate this setup using IIS Express.  I modified my applicationhost.config file within my .vs directory to contain the pointer to my nested web application -

```
<site name="MvcWwwRoot" id="2">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
          <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\MyMvcProjectDirectory\wwwroot" />
        </application>
        <application path="/One" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
          <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\MyWebFormsProjectDirectory" />
        </application>

...
</site>
```

When I launch the site through Visual Studio, I am able to see the nested application in the IIS Express viewer in the system tray.  However, I continually get 404 errors when attempting to access any of the pages in the nested application.  I have tried this with Mvc routing turned on or off and with various other different configuration changes, but nothing seems to work.  I have

```
<remove name="httpplatformhandler" />
```

added to the web.config of my webforms project.
Does anyone have any thoughts why this isn't working?  Is this setup even possible using IIS Express?

Comment: What kind of 404? Sub status? That's a big category.

Comment: sub status 0.....I'm not really getting any really meaningful error codes....

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/14

Comment: @Pawel - that post refers to IIS.  My site is working as expected when published to IIS.  The problem is with IIS Express.